# How to update windows forms application? If new Version is available means,put a notification alert to the user.

Tags: c#, winforms

How to update windows forms application? If new Version is available means,put a notification alert to the user.

I need a code for, if new ver found means, i want to update and run the application. User didn't update means, don't allow to run the application until he will update the application.

Comment: Microsoft has an easy way to do this through [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Read up on [ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx).

From MSDN:

> *ClickOnce is a deployment technology that enables you to create self-updating Windows-based applications that can be installed and run with minimal user interaction. Visual Studio provides full support for publishing and updating applications deployed with ClickOnce technology if you have developed your projects with Visual Basic and Visual C#.* - [Tell me more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx)

With ClickOnce the user can be notified that a new version is available and prompt them to accept the update.

ClickOnce gives you the option to specify a minimal version in which to run.  If the version is too old or the user declines the update the app will exit.

You can also force the update for silent updates.

In your WinForms project open up project properties and click the **Publish** tab.

### More

- *[ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx)*

Comment: This is a cool option. I was planning to implement this to my projects but I was not sure if such option exists.

Comment: @M.FawadSurosh I agree.  I just love how all the functionality can be achieved with zero programming too.   Essentially a wizard